# Tide SDK. How to read TEXT from txt file. Not binary data

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy, tidesdk

Please advise on how to read text from a txt or csv file using Tide SDK. I already tried the following:

```
var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.getDesktopDirectory(),'file.txt');
var fs = Ti.Filesystem.getFileStream(f);
fs.open(Ti.Filesystem.MODE_READ);
contents = fs.read();
```

But it returns a file object, not text from the file.

Answer (score 1):

This could help you,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Get path for app executable
  var p = Ti.Filesystem.getApplicationDirectory().parent().parent();

//Get file
  var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(p, "readtest.txt");

//Open filestream
  var fs = Ti.Filesystem.getFileStream(f);
  fs.open(Ti.Filesystem.MODE_READ);

//Get contents of file
  var c = fs.read(f.size());

//Show contents
  alert(c);
</script>
```

Comment: What's the difference with what I posted above? Just different directory? Your code and mine return a file object. But the question is how to get text from txt files...

Answer (score 0):

To get the text, use this:

```
var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.getDesktopDirectory(),'file.txt');
var content = f.read().text;
```

content is what you want.

Comment: Hi, I've already tried this. I found that on Titanium Mobile docs, but it doesn't work for Tide SDK. f.read().text or fs.read(f.text) return undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution. To get content of a file:

```
var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.getDesktopDirectory(),'yourfile.txt');
content = f.read().toString();
```

This does the trick and return a string of content.